How to Properly Execute Serialized Solana Transaction From Backend Using web3.js and Wallet Adapter?
Problem Description
I'm trying to execute a serialized Solana transaction on the frontend using Solana web3.js and Solana React Wallet Adapter. The transaction is provided by the backend as a hex string.
The main logic is as follows:

Deserialize the transaction using VersionedTransaction.deserialize().
Check for unsigned signatures and prompt the wallet for signing if required.
Submit the transaction using sendTransaction() or sendRawTransaction(), depending on the state of the signatures.
Wait for confirmation.

What’s Happening

I see the wallet popup and I successfully sign the transaction.
However, the transaction never appears in the Solana explorer.
There are no visible errors in the console, and no signature is returned from the wallet.

What I Have Tried

Deserialization:

I’m using VersionedTransaction.deserialize() and I confirmed that the transaction object is properly formed.
No errors during deserialization.


Signature Check:

I check if the transaction needs signing using:
const hasUnsignedSignatures = transaction.signatures.some((sig) => sig.every((byte) => byte === 0));





Serialized Transaction From Backend
This is an example of a serialized transaction I receive from the backend (it's in hex format). I’ve truncated the middle for security, but I can share the full version if required.
0x01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008001000713b557be...e963a0231f2f0919c4c

Note:

This is the actual transaction I receive from the backend.
I’m unsure if the format is correct or if any modifications are needed before deserializing.

Full Code Example
Here’s my full implementation for deserializing and executing the transaction.
 import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { SendTransactionError, VersionedTransaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

interface UseSolanaTransactionProps {
  onSuccess?: (signature: string) => void;
  onError?: (error: Error) => void;
  onTransactionHash?: (signature: string) => void;
}

const useSolanaTransaction = ({
  onSuccess,
  onError,
  onTransactionHash,
}: UseSolanaTransactionProps = {}) => {
  const { publicKey, signTransaction } = useWallet();
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const [isConfirmingSolana, setIsConfirmingSolana] = useState(false);

  const executeSolanaTransaction = async (hexString: string) => {
    try {
      setIsConfirmingSolana(true);
      if (!publicKey) {
        toast.error("Solana Wallet is not connected.");
        throw new Error("Wallet not connected");
      }

      if (!signTransaction) {
        throw new Error("signTransaction is undefined");
      }

      // Deserialize the transaction
      const transactionBuffer = new Uint8Array(
        Buffer.from(hexString.slice(2), "hex")
      );
      const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
      const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      // Update blockhash
      transaction.message.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

      // Check for unsigned signatures
      const hasUnsignedSignatures = transaction.signatures.some((sig) =>
        sig.every((byte) => byte === 0)
      );

      let signature: string;

      if (hasUnsignedSignatures) {
        // Sign and send transaction
        const signedTransaction = await signTransaction(transaction);
        const rawTransaction = signedTransaction.serialize();
        signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction);
      } else {
        // Send already signed transaction
        const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
        signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction);
      }

      // Call respondToSolution with pending and tx_hash
      onTransactionHash?.(signature);

      await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "finalized");

      console.log(
        `Transaction finalized on Solana Explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${signature}?cluster=mainnet-beta`
      );
      setIsConfirmingSolana(false);
      onSuccess?.(signature);
    } catch (error) {
      let errorMessage = "Error executing Solana transaction.";
      const e = error as Error;

      if (e instanceof SendTransactionError) {
        errorMessage = `Transaction failed: ${e.message}`;
      } else if (e.message.includes("BlockhashNotFound")) {
        errorMessage = "The blockhash used in the transaction has expired.";
      } else if (e.message.includes("TransactionExpired")) {
        errorMessage = "The transaction expired before being confirmed.";
      } else if (e.message.includes("RPCError")) {
        errorMessage = "There was an issue connecting to the Solana network.";
      }

      toast.error(errorMessage);
      console.error("Error executing Solana transaction:", e);
      setIsConfirmingSolana(false);
      onError?.(e);
      throw e;
    }
  };

  return { executeSolanaTransaction, isConfirmingSolana };
};

export default useSolanaTransaction;


What I’m Looking For
How should I properly handle the serialized transaction received from the backend?

Am I correctly deserializing the transaction?
Am I handling unsigned signatures correctly?

How do I ensure the transaction appears in Solana Explorer?

I see the wallet confirmation popup, but the transaction is never submitted to the blockchain.
I’m unsure if I should be using sendTransaction() or sendRawTransaction().


This code isn't actually doing any signing, it's just deserializing, resetting the blockhash, and then sending as is. So if you are missing signatures, you'll need to actually sign. Also, resetting the blockhash invalidates any existing signatures, which might be an issue. Most likely, these transactions are just immediately dropped by validators because they don't have signatures.

@JonC Any inputs how I can improve this, as I'm new in this? Any feedback on above code?

I'm not sure if this is LLM output, since there's a lot missing, or if it's just a tiny snippet, but things like publicKey and sendTransaction aren't defined or imported, so it's very tough to tell what's going on. At the very least, you might want to try using an appropriate Keypair to sign the transaction before sending it. You might want to go through the Solana Cookbook to see how things work. Check out https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/transactions/send-sol for example

@JonC I have updated the above code, which is the Solana hook that should execute any sterilized hash that I get dynamically from the backend side. In theory that should not be only sending SOL, it can be swapping any other coins on the Solana network.
The above code results that in most cases I get it fully working, but from time to time transaction is not initialized even though I get a confirm popup from the wallet.
Also, its says "confirmTransaction" its deprecated, so I have to check how to change that as well.

The biggest issue that I can see is always resetting the blockhash on the transaction -- if a blockhash is present in the transaction, you should just sign the transaction as is. After that, you'll need to provide some full transaction examples that are failing
